# prior visual studio 2010 instances required update

Tags: sql-server

I want to install sql server 2012 but i get this error :
[image: prior visual studio 2010 instances required update]

I was trying to install this package: 
[image: vb sp1]

When I click "re-run button" i got the same error!

Anyone have idea about the solution....?
Thanks

Comment: Did you try to install service pack one, for Visual Studio 2010?

Comment: did you "re-run" before or after installing service pack 1 of VS2010, as the error message states you need to do?

Comment: 1- did sp1 for vs2010 is same the package which i displayed it in above second image? i don't know the difference  between that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Download and install the Visual Studio 2010 Service Pack 1,

use this link `

> https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=23691

otherwise,
There are some common dependencies of the Visual Studio is crossing to SQL Server installation, So reintall the Visual Studio 2010 Service Pack 1 then try to install SQL Server

Comment: thanks i see this solution in many times but i want to know is this package is same attachment with sql server 2012 installation files ?? as i displayed in second above image ??

Comment: Can you check for Visual Studio 2010 Service Pack 1.